# Svelte Rollup [export name] is not exported by node_modules/

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, rollup

I am trying to import a module from [hyphen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyphen) like this: `import { hyphenateHTMLSync } from "hyphen/fr";` in the script tag of a Svelte module but I get `Error: 'hyphenateHTMLSync' is not exported by node_modules/hyphen/fr/index.js` from rollup.

The module file in quesiton looks like this:

**node_modules/hyphen/fr/index.js**

```
module.exports = require("../export-contract.js")(
    require("../patterns/fr.js")
);
```

**node_modules/hyphen/export-contract.js**

```
var createHyphenator = require("./hyphen.js");

module.exports = function (patterns) {
  return {
    hyphenate: createHyphenator(patterns, { async: true }),
    hyphenateHTML: createHyphenator(patterns, { async: true, html: true }),
    hyphenateHTMLSync: createHyphenator(patterns, { html: true }),
    hyphenateSync: createHyphenator(patterns),
    patterns: patterns
  };
};
```

And hyphen.js contains the function to create hyphenator.

I do not know enough of Rollup, Svelte or even Node to know how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Rollup requires extra plugins (`@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` and `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`) to deal with CommonJS modules, as explained [here](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#how-do-i-use-rollup-in-nodejs-with-commonjs-modules).

A very basic rollup example config using both plugins is given [here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#using-with-rollupplugin-node-resolve).

In your particular use case, if you still have issues using the basic config, you'll probably want to dig into the [dynamicRequireTargets](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#dynamicrequiretargets) option of the commonjs plugin.

Comment: Both plugins were already in my Rollup config file. I used the [Svelte template from degit](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) wich has them pre-configured. I gave a stab at using dynamicRequireTargets parameter for CommonJS, adding the 2 core components of the plugin and I still got the same problem. Unsure if I did something wrong with  dynamicRequireTargets. `commonjs( { dynamicRequireTargets: [ 'node_modules/hyphen/index.js', 'node_modules/hyphen/hyphen.js' ] } )`

Comment: For peace of mind, I would add all the modules involved in the dynamic import, i.e. `commonjs({ dynamicRequireTargets: [ 'node_modules/hyphen/export-contract.js', 'node_modules/hyphen/hyphen.js', 'node_modules/hyphen/patterns/fr.js' ] })`. If this doesn't work, then you might have to find another way around, namely by importing from `patterns/fr.js`, `hyphen.js` and calling `createHyphenator` manually (you could do all that in a separate JS file, export the result of the function call, and import that wherever needed in your project).

Comment: I ended up doing this last part, importing the `createHyphenator` and the patterns and exporting. Thank you for your help!